# How do I find the size of a non-proportional rectangle inside a given ellipse?

Tags: math

I understand how to calculate the largest possible rectangle that can be drawn inside an ellipse, but my problem is: I a have a rectangle of given proportions and an ellipse of a given size (not the same proportions) and I need to know how big that rectangle will be when centered inside the ellipse and sized with all four corners intersecting.

Answer (score 3):

If the rectangle is centered inside the ellipse, and for all 4 corners to lie on the ellipse, the 4 corners must be the solution to the equation system of:

**[1]** implicit equation of the ellipse: x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 = 1

**[2]** The proportion of the rectangle (aspect ratio) x / y = c.

Just substitute in and solve the equation for x and y. `2 * abs(x)` will be the width and `2 * abs(y)` will be the height of the rectangle.

Comment: Thanks, that works great. In my equation however, if c = x / y and I have a "vertical" rectangle, it must have a proportion > 1 then x = rect height and y = rect width. And solving for y yields the width. Does that make sense?

My Equation for solving y:
y = sqrt (b^2 / ((b^2 / a^2) * c^2) + 1))

Horizontal Ellipse and Vertical Rectangle

a = 60(h)  | a^2 = 3600
b = 130(w) | b^2 = 16900
x = 115(h)
y = 108(w)
c = x /y
c = 1.065 | c^2 = 1.134

y = sqrt (16900 / ((16900 / 3600) * 1.134) + 1))

y = 51.7
width = 2 * y = 103.4
height = 1.065 * y = 110

When drawn graphicaly, those dim are correct

Comment: Let's just call them dimensions of the rectangle. Width and height may be ambiguous. If it is correct for you, then everything is OK.